# Blackberry App Icon display in homescreen

Tags: blackberry, homescreen

I have successfully made an application but whenever I try installing it in the BOLD 9700 simulator, the icon gets displayed in the "Downloads" folder.

My client requires that his app's icon be displayed in the main menu i.e. that is outside the "Downloads" (in Homescreen).

I tried setting the HomeScreen position, but it just shuffles the position inside the "Downloads" folder.

Is there a method by which I can make my icon get displayed in the HomeScreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post on the BlackBerry Java Forums asking the same question - the response from RIM is that you cannot control where your application is placed - that is controlled by the theme. The only override for this is apps using the private RIM APIs that are not available to 3rd party developers (not even partners)

[Installing apps to folders other than downloads](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Configuration-that-makes-your-application-come-under/m-p/214695#M31460)

Comment: thanx a lot JustinD... i tried searching it myself but couldnt find the right keyword... This clears my problem... Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Spcfy_location_to_add_app_to_on_a_BB_device_893147_11.jsp) - we have tested it on OS5 and it does not work but according to [this forum thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/RIM-MIDlet-Position-1-and-Content-Folder-do-not-seem-to-work/td-p/509260) it should work on OS6.